# Unordered list of posts with different classes

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to create a unordered list with the last 3 posts from a category, with for each LI a different class.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=3'); ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
            <br />
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Please teach me how to add a different class for each LI. By example i want to have red, blue and brown class names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code, special class for all posts:

```
<li class="myspecialclassname_<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

or for example you can use a counter for ordered colored list:

```
<?php 
    function get_color($id) { 
        if ($id%3 == 0){return "red";} 
        else if ($id%3 == 1){return "blue";} 
        else if ($id%3 == 2){return "brown";} 
    }
?>
<?php query_posts('cat=3'); ?>
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li class="<?php get_color($counter++); ?>">
            <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
            <br />
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Special class for all posts is working, but unfortunately is not an option. The first class must be 'red' always, as the second class 'blue' and the third class 'brown'.

Unfortunately your code for dynamic color classes is not working. The result is empty..

Comment: Sorry, i am late to response. First of all, you must create a get_color() function on functions.php. this function include if's like this:

    get_color($id){
       if ($id%3 == 0){return "red"}
       elseif ($id%3 == 1){return "blue"}
       elseif ($id%3 == 2){return "brown}
    }

Comment: Hi Hkulekci, I tried but that is giving an Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' error. My fuction is now as follows:
function get_color($id) {
 if ($id%3 == 0){return "red"}
 elseif ($id%3 == 1){return "blue"}
 elseif ($id%3 == 2){return "brown"}
}

Comment: i am experienced on wordpress and change my code like this. i hope this will not give any error. i did not use functions.php file. You can use to implement get_color() function.

Comment: Hi Hkulekci. I tried your edited code. The posts are displayed without error now but the class property stays empty in every LI.

Comment: first of all you can try to change this line `<li class="<?php get_color($counter++); ?>">` with this `<li class="color_<?php get_color($counter++); ?>">`. if you can see "color_"'s on the li class, our function is false. if you cant see anything, you change wrong file. After that, if our function is false, you can change this line `else if ($id%3 == 2){return "brown";}` with this `else {return "brown";}`. In this situation, function must return something. We control to return something strictly with this changings.

Comment: Hi Hkulekci. It works now! I changed to function to this: <?php 
    function get_color($id) { 
        if ($id%3 == 0){echo "red";} 
        else if ($id%3 == 1){echo "blue";} 
        else {echo "brown";} 
    }
?> Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a method to return the class to use for the li element. Let's assume you have a red, blue and brown class in your css, you could do it like so:

```
<?php 
query_posts('cat=3');
$elt_count = 0;
while(have_posts()) : 
    the_post();
    $elt_count++;
?>
    <li class="<?php get_class_for_li_elt($elt_count); ?>">
         <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
         <br />
         <?php the_content(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

with the medhod `get_class_for_li_elt($elt_count)` returning echoing red for element #1, blue for element #2 and brown for element #3.

Comment: Hi Eric, this is returning the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE in. In any case, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi Eric, unfortunately it doesn't. Error is now: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE.

Comment: Yes I don't have php setup right now. These are just syntax errors. Tested it online. Should work now. Finally.

Comment: Hi Eric,

I tried but this results in an empty list. Other ideas ;-)?

Comment: It must be because your function have_post returns false. I can't help you on this unfortunately.